# Is there a way to copy file located on my website directory into my local drive with access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a legacy vba program that am trying to implement an software update functionality for. This will require me to copy the update from a location on our site and save temporary on the user system.

I have implemented the updater on the desktop but am having issue copying the patch from our site. I have tried some suggestion to use \oursite.com\folder\file.txt for example, but this has not worked for me as it is saying file not found.

```
 downloadPaths(0) = "\\oursite.com\foldername\update\test.txt"

'once we have our folder in place, we will download the current update
' and save in the current local folder
If (IsArray(downloadPaths)) Then
    ' we will loop over each download patches to get from source
    For Each updatepath In downloadPaths
        If (updatepath <> "") Then
            If (fs.FileExists(updatepath)) Then
            ' do whatever here 
            end if 
         end if 
     next
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as nobody attempt to answer this question, I have decided to post the solution I came up with. It is dirty, but it does get the job done, and the software update functionality is completed. Please note that in validating successful download, the response to check for will be determine by your server. I use Apache, Mysql, and Php 5 >.

```
Public Function downloadFileFromUrl(sourceUrl As Variant, destinationPath As Variant) As Boolean

On Error GoTo downloadFileFromUrlError

Dim validFile As Boolean

  'It takes a url (sourceUrl) and downloads the URL to destinationPath.

      With New WinHttpRequest
          'Open a request to our source
          .Open "GET", sourceUrl

          'Set this to get it to go through the firewall
          .SetAutoLogonPolicy AutoLogonPolicy_Always
          .SetProxy 2, "http://127.0.0.1:8888", "*.never"
          .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "*/*"

          'Set any options you may need http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384108(v=vs.85).aspx
          'Set a custom useragent, not needed, but could be useful if there are problems on the server
          .Option(WinHttpRequestOption_UserAgentString) = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; VBA Wget)"

          'Automatically follow any redirects
          .Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = "True"

          .Send

          ' check if the download is a valid file before we write to file
            If (isValidFileDownload(.responseText)) Then
                'Write the responseBody to a file
                Dim ado As New ADODB.Stream
                ado.Type = adTypeBinary
                ado.Open
                ado.Write .ResponseBody
                ado.SaveToFile destinationPath, adSaveCreateOverWrite
                ado.Close
                downloadFileFromUrl = True    'download was successful
            Else
                downloadFileFromUrl = False    'download was not successful
            End If

      End With

      downloadFileFromUrlExit:
      On Error Resume Next
      Set ado = Nothing
      Exit Function

      downloadFileFromUrlError:

      downloadFileFromUrl = False    'An error occurred
      Select Case Err
      Case Else
          Debug.Print "Unhandled Error", Err.Number, Err.description, Err.Source, Erl()
      End Select
      Resume downloadFileFromUrlExit
   Resume
```

End Function

```
Private Function isValidFileDownload(responseText As Variant) As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
If (InStr(1, left(responseText, 1000), "<h1>Object not found!</h1>")) Then
    Exit Function
Else
    isValidFileDownload = True
End If
```

End Function